# Python argparse - arguments strip off when bash special character is passed as argument

Tags: python, bash, argparse

I writing CLI tool using argparse.

Below is my code snippet:

```
parser.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--username')
parser.add_argument('--password')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.password)
```

I run the script on my Mac:

`>>> prog.py --username xyz --password abc$xyz`

Output:

`>>> abc`

I know it's bash shell that interprets '$xyz' as a bash variable and tries to substitute '$xyz'

Is there are way I can get around this without enclosing the password in quotes?

Comment: backspace escapes the dollar sign, so you can do: \$xyz

Comment: This isn't a Python problem, this is a *how do I escape special characters in bash* question.

Comment: I know it isn't a Python problem and I even know how to escape special characters in bash. @dkasak answered it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a backslash in front of the `$`: `prog.py --username xyz --password abc\$xyz`.

Otherwise, no. You correctly observed that it is bash that is doing this so, by the time Python/argparse receives the command, there is nothing that can be done.